# Seamless CSS class transitions with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to use jquery.ui's class transition animations on my website. Everything works fine in Firefox, but jquery.ui throws when running the same animation in IE.

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-dev/browse_thread/thread/b165405b979775ed) describes exactly the same problem I am having and mentions that there is a jquery.ui branch by Alexander Farkas which fixes it. Unfortunately the [link to the branch](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/dev/effects/ui/effects.core.js) is not working anymore. I've tried the latest version trunk (1.8a) of jquery.ui effects.core, but it did not solve the problem, so I assume this must not be it.

Does anyone know where this branch can be downloaded? Or is there any other (more stable) plugin for seamless animations between two css classes? I don't really need the other jquery.ui stuff anyway.

*Disclaimer*: I already know this can also be done by hand with style transitions. I'd really prefer a css-based version though since it does not tie javascript code to styling information.

Comment: No answer here, but I can confirm that I've seen this problem as well in IE, and worked around it using manual `animate` calls with carefully-crafted color values. A fix in jQuery UI would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch has moved here:

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/effects/ui/effects.core.js

I'm pleased to say it does fix the problem I've been having with jquery.ui and class transitions in IE!.